# What is the nth partial derivative of a spherical mean?

Tags: calculus

I was wondering, what the n-th partial derivative of the radius over a spherical mean is, ergo:
$$ \partial_r ^n \frac{1}{A^{k} r^{k-1}} \int_{\partial B(x, r)} u(y) dS(y)$$
where $A^{n}$ is tne surface area of the n-dimensional unit sphere. I know, that for $n = 1$ this is
$$ \partial_r \frac{1}{A^{k} r^{k-1}} \int_{\partial B(x, r)} u(y) dS(y) = \frac{1}{A^{k} r^{k-1}} \int_{\partial B(x, r)} Du(y)\frac{y - x}{r} dS(y)$$
However I haven't been able to extend this for an n-th partial derivative and also haven't found any resources on this.
Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: Why is the $n$th derivative of interest? Usually this derivative is of interest to prove the averaging property of harmonic functions, but in that case only the first derivative is needed.

Comment: @K.defaoite IIRC it probably comes up in the solution to the wave equation in higher dimensions.

Comment: @peek-a-boo yes